# Multi Dimensional array, display certain values from array index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 2 [1] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 4 [1] => 4 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 8 [1] => 8 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 16 [1] => 16 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 32 [1] => 32 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 64 [1] => 64 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 128 [1] => 128 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [Name] => Exterior Hoist [0] => Exterior Hoist [ConditionValue] => 256 [1] => 256 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 512 [1] => 512 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1024 [1] => 1024 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 2048 [1] => 2048 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 4096 [1] => 4096 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 8192 [1] => 8192 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 16384 [1] => 16384 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 32768 [1] => 32768 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [Name] => Parcel [0] => Parcel [ConditionValue] => 65536 [1] => 65536 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [Name] => Cheques [0] => Cheques [ConditionValue] => 131072 [1] => 131072 )
    [18] => Array ( [Name] => OuterArea [0] => OuterArea [ConditionValue] => 262144 [1] => 262144 ) 
    [19] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 524288 [1] => 524288 ) 
    [20] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 1048576 [1] => 1048576 ) 
    [21] => Array ( [Name] => V [0] => V [ConditionValue] => 2097152 [1] => 2097152 )
    [22] => Array ( [Name] => Wheelchair [0] => Wheelchair [ConditionValue] => 4194304 [1] => 4194304 ) 
    [23] => Array ( [Name] => M50 [0] => M50 [ConditionValue] => 8388608 [1] => 8388608 ) 
    [24] => Array ( [Name] => Executive Car (Silver) [0] => Executive Car (Silver) [ConditionValue] => 16777216 [1] => 16777216 ) 
    [25] => Array ( [Name] => Two M50s [0] => Two M50s [ConditionValue] => 33554432 [1] => 33554432 ) 
    [26] => Array ( [Name] => Special [0] => Special [ConditionValue] => 67108864 [1] => 67108864 ) 
    [27] => Array ( [Name] => Animal [0] => Animal [ConditionValue] => 134217728 [1] => 134217728 ) 
    [28] => Array ( [Name] => COD Parcel [0] => COD Parcel [ConditionValue] => 268435456 [1] => 268435456 ) 
    [29] => Array ( [Name] => 9 seater [0] => 9 seater [ConditionValue] => 536870912 [1] => 536870912 ) 
    [30] => Array ( [Name] => 6 seater [0] => 6 seater [ConditionValue] => 1073741824 [1] => 1073741824 ) 
    [31] => Array ( [Name] => 7 seater [0] => 7 seater [ConditionValue] => 2147483648 [1] => 2147483648 ) 
    [32] => Array ( [Name] => Wagon [0] => Wagon [ConditionValue] => 4294967296 [1] => 4294967296 ) 
    [33] => Array ( [Name] => Maxi10str [0] => Maxi10str [ConditionValue] => 8589934592 [1] => 8589934592 ) 
    [34] => Array ( [Name] => Bike [0] => Bike [ConditionValue] => 17179869184 [1] => 17179869184 ) 
    [35] => Array ( [Name] => NonMaxi [0] => NonMaxi [ConditionValue] => 34359738368 [1] => 34359738368 ) 
    [36] => Array ( [Name] => NonMaxiOrMulti [0] => NonMaxiOrMulti [ConditionValue] => 68719476736 [1] => 68719476736 ) 
    [37] => Array ( [Name] => [0] => [ConditionValue] => 137438953472 [1] => 137438953472 ) 
    [38] => Array ( [Name] => Towbar [0] => Towbar [ConditionValue] => 274877906944 [1] => 274877906944 ) 
    [39] => Array ( [Name] => NO DISPATCH [0] => NO DISPATCH [ConditionValue] => 549755813888 [1] => 549755813888 ) )
```

I have a reasonably simple multi dimensional array, that i want to display the "name" of a certain array index...

for example say i have the value 22, i want to be able to display "wheelchair".

i get a little lost when it comes to the second dimension.

thus far i have tried..

$result is the multidimensional array above.

$resulting_bits is this array (it is built dynamically and could have up to 40 values):

```
Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 26 [2] => 33 )
```

this is the code i have at the moment

```
foreach($resulting_bits as $val) {

echo $val;

echo "<br>";

$answer = ($result[$val]);

foreach($answer as $conditionname) {


print_r ($conditionname);
echo "<br>";
echo $conditionname[Name];
}
```

this gives me

```
Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 26 [2] => 33 )
23
M50
MM50
M8388608
88388608
826
Special
SSpecial
S67108864
667108864
633
Maxi10str
MMaxi10str
M8589934592
88589934592
8
```

which seems odd to me... how do i just display the "name"??

Comment: `echo $result[22]["Name"]` ? Or do you need an iteration?

Comment: "$resulting_bits is this array (it is built dynamically and could have up to 40 values):" What do you mean by "this array"?

Are you saying that you want to retreive all of the name's that correspond to the indexes stored in $resulting_bits?\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second for loop is unnecessary! It is not an associative array at that point.

```
foreach($resulting_bits as $val) {

echo $val;

echo "<br>";

$answer = ($result[$val]);
$name = $answer['Name'];
echo $name;

}
```

I would personnaly just do:

```
foreach($resulting_bits as $val) {

   echo $result[$val]['Name'];

}
```

Comment: the question states "$result is the multidimensional array above"